# Google sitemap.xml two applications

Tags: seo, google, wordpress, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I have a site and a blog.

My domain is so: mysite.com and my blog is so mysite.com/blog. The two are the same server. I have only a sitemap.xml. "mysite.com/sitemap.xml"
I have to include the blog posts in the sitemap.xml or not? I want Google understand mysite as being the same.
How I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sitemaps are not generally necessary.*

For most sites, sitemaps are only used by Google to ensure that they can effectively crawl your site by comparing the results of a crawl with the sitemap. Where a sitemap is necessary is for extremely large sites, sites that cannot be effectively crawled, sites with a paywall or login.

*Sitemaps do nothing for SEO.*

If your site can be properly crawled, you do not need a sitemap, however, if you do provide one, do not confuse Google and make it complete. It is possible that you can use both sitemaps by using an index sitemap. An index sitemap points to other sitemaps. You can get the information on index sitemaps here: http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index

In your case, you would generate your separate sitemaps, name/rename them appropriately, then use the index sitemap to reference the files created. You can very easily hand edit your index sitemap.

*What happens if you do not include your blog sitemap?*

Nothing. Google will compare your sitemap against what they find in their crawl. However, if Google finds more pages than what exist in your sitemap, it may discount your sitemap entirely. Otherwise, the only cost is effort. You will be wasting your time and effort.

Remember that if Google can effectively crawl your site, it will continue to do so. If there is no difference between a crawl and the sitemap, the sitemap is largely ignored.

Again. Sitemaps are not necessary. Yes, I know that half the planet recommends one, but it is false advice parroted around out of ignorance of how a sitemap is actually used.

Answer (score 0):

As closetnoc mentioned, you don't have to have a sitemap. Just make sure Google can access the link. This means don't use any `rel="nofollow"` or any other nofollow directives on links you want google to follow and it will have an easier time finding new content.

However, you should include one if you want to keep track of how many URLs on your site google has indexed on their search engine out of how many you advertised in your sitemap. You can see such progress in the sitemaps section in Google Webmaster Tools.